# What is another way of saying "and more"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

What is another of way saying "and more" in this sentence?

Throughout my life, I have discovered the love for science, mathematics, and literature, all the way to visual arts, badminton, and more.

Comment: And+ some more, a lot more, few more, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *et cetera* can be used here.